# SQL query to find results with no gap in dates

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table with ClaimNumber, NoteCreateDate, NoteType

I wanted to find the claims that has notes like 'Review sent' back to back with no gap in the NoteCreateDate

eg.

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
| ClaimNumber | NoteCreateDate |       Notes        | NoteType |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
|       12121 | 12/01/2017     | ReviewSent         | Subject  |
|       12121 | 12/05/2017     | PackagesenttoABC   | Details  |
|       12121 | 12/07/2017     | ReviewSent         | Subject  |
|       10005 | 05/06/2018     | ReviewSent         | Subject  |
|       10005 | 05/07/2018     | ReviewSent         | Subject  |
|       10005 | 05/08/2018     | ReviewSent         | Subject  |
|       10005 | 05/12/2018     | Fieldinvestigation | SIU      |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
```

**Expected**
From this example I wanted only the claim number **10005** since it the claim that has the notes 'Review Sent' back to back with no gap in the date(consecutive Dates). For instance, I wanted to find the claims that has the note with phrase 'ReviewSent' created today and the following note should also be the same 'Review sent', no matter when it was created, May be the next day or even 10 days later .. Thanks in Advance

**My current MS SQL query.**

```
    select cm.ClaimNum, a.NoteCreateDate, a.Notes, a.NoteType 
        from CMaster cm
        left join Note a on cm.ClaimNum = a.PARENTREF
        left join NoteType] b on b.ID = a.TYPECODE 
        where Body like '%Review Sent%'
```

Comment: "back to back with no gap in the NoteCreateDate" can you define this condition? I can't see the rule looking at the dates... do you mean at least 2 consecutive days?

Comment: yeah exactly.. I wanted to know the claims that has the phrase like 'ReviewSent' in consecutive days..

Comment: can the dates ever be the same for a claim number?

Comment: yeah.. the dates can be same for a claim number. for eg. I wanted to find the claims that has the note with phrase 'ReviewSent' created today  and the following  note should also be the same 'Review sent', no matter when it was created, May be the next day or even 10 days later.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to find the ClaimNumber(s) where the ReviewSent notes are sent back-2-back then this query will get them

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    ([ClaimNumber] int, [NoteCreateDate] datetime, [Notes] varchar(18), [NoteType] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO T1
    ([ClaimNumber], [NoteCreateDate], [Notes], [NoteType])
VALUES
    (12121, '2017-12-01 00:00:00', 'ReviewSent', 'Subject'),
    (12121, '2017-12-05 00:00:00', 'PackagesenttoABC', 'Details'),
    (12121, '2017-12-07 00:00:00', 'ReviewSent', 'Subject'),
    (10005, '2018-05-06 00:00:00', 'ReviewSent', 'Subject'),
    (10005, '2018-05-07 00:00:00', 'ReviewSent', 'Subject'),
    (10005, '2018-05-08 00:00:00', 'ReviewSent', 'Subject'),
    (10005, '2018-05-12 00:00:00', 'Fieldinvestigation', 'SIU')
;

SELECT DISTINCT X.ClaimNumber
FROM(
    SELECT
         ClaimNumber
        ,NoteCreateDate
        ,Notes
        ,NoteType
        ,LD=LEAD( Notes )OVER(PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY NoteCreateDate ASC)
    FROM dbo.T1
) X WHERE LD= 'ReviewSent' AND X.Notes= 'ReviewSent'

DROP TABLE dbo.T1
```

Result

```
ClaimNumber
10005
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select * into #tmp
    from
   (
       Select   12121  as ClaimNumber,'12/01/2017' as 
      NoteCreateDate,'ReviewSent' as Notes,'Subject' as NoteType
     union
     Select 12121 , '12/05/2017'     , 'PackagesenttoABC'   , 'Details'  
     union
     Select       12121 , '12/07/2017'     , 'ReviewSent'         , 
     'Subject'  
     union
    Select       10005 , '05/06/2018'     , 'ReviewSent'         , 'Subject'  
   union
     Select       10005 , '05/07/2018'     , 'ReviewSent'         , 
       'Subject'  
   union
   Select       10005 , '05/08/2018'     , 'ReviewSent'         , 'Subject'  
     union
  Select       10005 , '05/12/2018'     , 'Fieldinvestigation' , 'SIU'  

  ) t

/*create another temp table to simplify the query*/
 Select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY 
 ClaimNumber) 
  as ClaimCounter  into #tmp2 from #tmp

  /** finally get the claimnos that have consecutive NoteCreate Date **/
  SELECT distinct t1.ClaimNumber FROM #tmp2 t1
   inner join #tmp2 t2 on (t1.ClaimCounter = t2.ClaimCounter - 1 and 
   t1.ClaimNumber = t2.ClaimNumber)
  where 
  DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.NoteCreateDate,t2.NoteCreateDate) = 1 
  and
  t1.Notes ='ReviewSent' and t2.Notes ='ReviewSent'
```